# Working with External server inside Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, vpn, vpc, amazon-vpc

I have an external server hosted and managed on my side. There's another server I use, which is based on Amazon EC2. I would like to get them to work together using Amazon VPC (Virtual Private Cloud).

Is that possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to migrate your EC2 instance to a VPC, then no, you can not. You will require to create a new instance inside your VPC and replicate the setup and data. The fastest way to accomplish this is creating an AMI from your current EC2 instance and deploy it as a new instance inside VPC.

Furthermore, if your VPC instance is deployed in a private subnet, you will have to deploy a public NAT instance, configure the NAT instance DST-NAT rules to map external ports to your app instance, setup the VPC routing tables properly and adjust the security groups in order to allow forwarding traffic.

Now, about the external server, if you are going to migrate it to VPC, I would recommend you to directly create a new instance with a prebuilt standard Amazon AMI and then manully replicate configuration and data. There are some [VM migration tools](https://aws.amazon.com/es/ec2/vm-import/) but my experience with such tools has not been friendly so...